# Convert String to Datetime in dd.MM.yyyy format without hours C#

Tags: c#, sql, date, datetime, converters

I've searched whole site and Google and couldn't find what I really need. I am trying to select records from SQL server DB between 2 dates (DB column is in date format not datetime). I take the dates from two TextBox (21.8.2014 format) and query is `BirthDay >= dateTxt1 AND BirthDay<=dateTxt2` 
dateTxt1 and dateTxt2 should be a DateTime not a string. 
Please do not offer me to use ToShortDateTimeString("dd.MM.yyyy"). I want something like this:

```
DateTime ddateTxt1 =Convert.toDateTime(TextBox1.Text, "dd.MM.yyyy");
```

Is that possible? output should be like 21.8.2014, not like 21.8.2014 00:00:00 
How can I get the value from TextBox and convert it to DateTime and make a query.

I've tried belov code but didn't work:

```
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;        

DateTime theDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(TextBox1.Text, "d.MMMM.yyyy", provider);
```

Thank you

Comment: It's not really clear what the problem is.  Does the user input from `TextBox1` include hours/minutes/seconds?  How are you outputting this value?  `DateTime` values are formatted for *output*, not necessarily for *input*.  A `DateTime` value itself is just data, it doesn't have a format or culture info.  Where are you seeing these hour/minute/second values that you don't want?

Comment: In addition to what previous comment ask for; how are you querying db? and which version SQL is it?

Comment: SQL server 2012 - My query is: "Select * From db Where Active=true AND birthDay >= dateTextBox1 AND birthDay <= dateTextBox2"; birthDay in DB is in date format (21.8.2014) and dateTextBox is in DateTime format (21.8.2014 00:00:00). So it returns no data. I am getting the DateTime dateTextBox1 = Convert.toDateTime(TextBox1.Text); TextBox1.Text is 21.8.2014 but dateTextBox1 is 21.8.2014 00:00:00. So I want a variable in DateTime format but without hours and seconds. I hope I could explain. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
DateTime outdate = new DateTime();
DateTime date = DateTime.TryParse(TextBox1.Text,out outdate);
```

then

```
String EndDate = (DateTime)date.ToShortDateString();
```

Comment: the last line won't work.  As you already have the date time.  You could use `date.Date` to remove the time component.

Comment: I don't want the output as string. It should be in DateTime but without hours,minutes and seconds. So ToShortDateString is not answer for me. dateTextBox1.Date is giving me output same (21.8.2014 00:00:00) I don't know why but output is giving the same value of it.